# Android client - Java Server and Tor traffic

Tags: java, android, server, client, tor

I am trying to set up a java server and an Android client whose communication is via Tor. Using [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/silvertunnel-ng/wiki/Netlib%20Direct%20API%20Usage/) pages instructions I have managed to do so, using a Java client. But when I am trying to use the client side code to Android project the app crashes. My android-client code is below.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private BootStrapper bootstrapper;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bootstrapper = new BootStrapper();
    bootstrapper.execute();

}

 @Override

     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


             getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
             return true;
 }

 private class BootStrapper extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

    TcpipNetAddress remoteAddress = new TcpipNetAddress("localhost", 3000);
    NetLayer netLayer = NetFactory.getInstance().getNetLayerById(NetLayerIDs.TCPIP);
    netLayer.waitUntilReady();


    try {
        NetSocket netSocket = netLayer.createNetSocket(null, null, remoteAddress);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;}


        }




    }
```

I am having not errors in the server side but on the client side this is the output of the logCat

```
06-07 22:07:26.981: W/dalvikvm(2364): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2065 (Lorg/silvertunnel_ng/netlib/api/util/TcpipNetAddress;) in Lcom/example/hellotor/MainActivity$BootStrapper;
```

Comment: the app crashes => please [edit] your question and add the stacktrace you get.

Comment: Thanks! Just edited! I would appreciate any kind of help

Answer (score 0):

Hello try not to use this library on android because it has overall problems with the memory. Consider to take a look at this [library](https://github.com/PanagiotisDrakatos/T0rlib4Android) for android. it is new, functional and fully updated